# How to make sequence diagram parallel activities

Tags: diagram

In my application the "System" capture screenshots and store it in local then in server,
at the same time count key stroke and mouse click and store it in server and local and same time also keep record of last two minutes and store it local and after random time store it server ,,, how i can display in sequence diagram the work of the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Combined Fragment element of type parallel, or element coregion (alternative to combined fragmetn). These two elements define concurent execution in sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This can be done in sequence diagrams. Not only parallel,You can show loops, breaks and if else etc in sequence diagrams.You have to learn [combined fragment](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html) which is a sub-type of interaction fragment, to do that.